# Susbtring from a data table column

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, substring

Can anyone help me with this?

I have a datatable 'dt' which is filled from the database.
I have a couple of columns my dt which I need to substring. I want to chop off characters after a particular character(=). and push it back to my dt.

I have been trying different things but nothing works. I am sure I am missing something.

```
private DataTable MyTableWhenExport(DataTable dt) {
    if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
        (dt.Columns["MyColumn"]) = dt["yMyColumn"]
            .Substring(0, dt["MyColumn"].LastIndexOf("=") + 1); // My substring code here
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Can someone help me with this, please

Comment: What have you tried? Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for your response,. I have added my function. Appreciate your help

Comment: Since you're new here (welcome!), please always remember to also include the exception you get and point out clearly where it gets thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that for every row in your table, you have to do something like this:

```
    DataTable MyTableWhenExport(DataTable dt)
    {
        // insert argument checking here

        foreach (var dataRow in dt.AsEnumerable())
        {
            var value = dataRow.Field<string>("MyColumn");

            if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(value))
            {
                // handle accordingly
            }
            else
            {
                value = value.Substring(0, value.LastIndexOf('=') + 1);
                dataRow.SetField("MyColumn", value);
            }
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

Note that you can't access row values by indexing the `DataTable` directly.

Also, this answer assumes you have LINQ at your disposal.

Please note that, if there's the chance the string might not contain `=`, `LastIndexOf` would return `-1`. I haven't tested, but it looks like in that case the content would be truncated (or an exception thrown, if `Substring` doesn't like you to ask for a substring of length 0. I can't remember).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
string firstPart = theString.Split('=')[0];
```

to retrieve the part before `=`. If the string does not contain an equal sign, this returns the whole string.

If the string can be `null`, use

```
string firstPart = theString?.Split('=')[0];
```

---

You must access the rows of the `DataTable`. `dt.Columns` only contains the column definitions (like the Caption), not the actual cell values.

```
DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
string oldValue = (string)row["MyColumn"];  // Returns an object. Therefore cast to string.
row["MyColumn"] = oldValue?.Split('=')[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This does not work. I have added my code. Please see if that helps. Appreciate any help

Comment: "does not work" is not a helpful explanation. What does happen? Are you getting an compiler error, a runtime exception, which one?

Answer (score 0):

What code do you already have?

I suppose you need something like:

```
dt["yourColumn"] = dt["yourColumn"].Substring(0, dt["yourColumn"].LastIndexOf("=") + 1);
```

Good luck!

Edit:
Sorry, my above answer is completely wrong! It has been a long time I worked with datasets and datatables (Entity Framework renders this obsolete).
You first need to refer to the row you want to modify, and then the column (i.e. the field).

Something like:

```
dt[0]["yourColumn"] = dt[0]["yourColumn"].Substring(0, dt[0]["yourColumn"].LastIndexOf("=") + 1);
```

The 0 there is the index of the row you want to change.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This does not work. I have added my code. Please see if that helps. Appreciate any help

Comment: Are you sure the dt contains rows? Did you try to debug to see what happens exactly? You are not getting an error are you?

Comment: The parentheses at the left side of the assignment are a bit weird, I think it's better to remove them.
So  dt.Columns["MyColumn"] = ...  instead of (dt.Columns["MyColumn"]) = ...

Comment: dt contains data. After I make changes based on your suggestion I get below error </br> Property or indexer 'DataColumnCollection.this[string]' cannot be assigned to
 DataColumn' does not contain a definition for 'Substring' and no accessible extension method 'Substring' accepting a first argument of type 'DataColumn' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
         DataColumn' does not contain a definition for 'LastIndexOf' and no accessible extension method 'LastIndexOf' accepting a first argument of type 'DataColumn' could be found

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Cf. my edited answer. Olivier's answer is even better... :-)